# Symfony2 using both CAS and login/password authentification

Tags: symfony, authentication, cas

I need to create a portal for my website using two authentication protocols.

- Using a standard approach with login / password
- Using a CAS service

So, when a user arrives on the homepage he can choose one of these two authentication systems.

I am not very skilled in security in symfony2, so I have follow the Symfony documentation to write this code:

```html
#Security.yml

security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    firewalls:
        secure_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            context: form_auth
            form_login:
                login_path:  /form_login
                check_path:  /form_login_check
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /riac

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/riac/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    bob:  { password: bob, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }
        main:
            entity: { class: Riac\HomeBundle\Entity\Login, property: username }
```

This one works fine for the login/password approach.

To create the CAS protocol I have found BeSimpleSsoAuthBundle, but... problems....

So I have read the installation documentation to implement this one and I have success to run it alone (with no login/password protocol). For now to implement both protocols at once I have written this code:

```html
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    firewalls:

        cas_secure_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            context: cas_auth
            trusted_sso:
                manager: admin_sso
                login_action: false
                logout_action: false
                login_path:  /cas_login
                check_path:  /cas_login_check
                create_users: true
                created_users_roles: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]
                check_path: /form_login_check
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /riac

        secure_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            context: form_auth
            form_login:
                login_path:  /form_login
                check_path:  /form_login_check
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /riac

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/riac/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    bob:  { password: bob, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }
        main:
            entity: { class: Riac\HomeBundle\Entity\Login, property: username }
```

But it doesn't work (logout problem, login_check not found, difficulty to identify what method to use).

So I think that is not the best methodology,  but I don't know how do this. Can you help me please?